# How to sort numbers in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to pass the following argument and print sorted numbers on the terminal. I used the following command line argument:

```
$ echo "7 3 1 5 11" | ruby sort.rb
```

I tried this sample code:

```
sort_no = gets.chomp()
array = []
a = array.push(sort_no)
b = a.sort(&:to_i)
puts "#{b}"
```

The output is:

```
["7 3 1 5 11"]
```

Comment: You're passing in a string and never splitting it into the various integers.

Comment: What is your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pushing to your array what sort_no stores, that's your "whole" string `"7 3 1 5 11"`, which can't be sorted that way.

As the array contains just one value, then it does a sort, in its way.

You could split each number and this way you get an array with each number, and then sort them:

```
gets.chomp.split.map(&:to_i).sort # [1, 3, 5, 7, 11]
```

This just gets the input, split it on each whitespace, map each value to an integer object, and then you're able to sort it.

Notice is also possible to sort the input introduced after spliting it without mapping the values, in case you want to keep the values as strings:

```
gets.chomp.split.sort_by(&:to_i) # ["1", "3", "5", "7", "11"]
```

Comment: `split` without argument ignores leading and trailing whitespace, so you don't need `chomp`.

Answer (score 0):

you are passing a string. so you can convert into array and do sort operation
later you can convert to string object:

```
a="7 3 1 5 11"
b= a.split(' ').map(&:to_i).sort
puts b.join(' ')
```